# Categories gone after changing theme / demos

Tags: themes

When I try to change the theme from other developer or even demos from the same theme creator some categories will be removed 
Tried checking hidden categories or even find them on SQL DB but nothing. Googled but none helped or suited my issue

Comment: Normally a category will only be removed/deleted when there is a function/plugin doing it or is done manually. So you need to do a search for such a function/plugin in those themes which would delete catgories. (which I doubt is done by a(ny) theme) Are you sure you talk about categories?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replay
Yea im not a newbi but recently mived from joomla and dotnet to wo
I have over 17 cats and 6-8 cats are removing each time i try to change theme or install different demos of the same theme .. struggled over the net but no result found 
I didnt add any custom function but a function to add new post views count cause i lost all my post views